# JQuery - Check every ASP CheckBox for Checked property and fadeTo if Checked

Tags: jquery

This is my first question so please let me know if I did anything wrong.  Anyhow, what I'm trying to do is, upon document complete, check to see if any checkboxes are checked and then fade those paragraph elements as indicated in the inner-most code below.  In terms of the code which actual does the fadeTo, I know it's correct because I use it in another part of the code.  And I know that it's finding at least one checked element because I get the 'alert' shown in the code below.  However, the associated elements are not fading.  Any suggestions?

Other info: Checkboxes are properly checked (per the rest of my application) in html when I look at the source code.  The checkboxes are asp.net.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 0) {
        $(this).closest('p').fadeTo('mid', '0.25')
        $(this).closest('p').children().fadeTo('mid', '0.25')
        $(this).closest('p').next().children('li').fadeTo('mid', '0.25')
        alert("It worked.")
    };
});
```

Comment: you need to share the html as well

Comment: `this` refers to document here! `document` doesn't have any `p` as ancestor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the dom ready handler `this` refers to the `document` object.

From what I can see you are trying to target the ancestor element(`p`) of the checked checkboxes and few other elements related to it.

So first you need to get the `p` elements for that you can use `$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest('p')` then find other elements in relation to these elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $ps = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest('p');
    $ps.fadeTo('mid', '0.25')
    $ps.children().fadeTo('mid', '0.25')
    $ps.next().children('li').fadeTo('mid', '0.25')
});
```

Comment: I shall sing the praises of Arun P Johny from the top of the mountains!  As soon as it allows me, I will mark your response as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the original code did not check the `.length` but called a `.each()` on the set..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() { // only this line was altered
        $(this).closest('p').fadeTo('mid', '0.25')
        $(this).closest('p').children().fadeTo('mid', '0.25')
        $(this).closest('p').next().children('li').fadeTo('mid', '0.25')
        alert("It worked.")
    };
});
```